# Setting up MapServer with existing XAMPP

Tags: mapserver, windows, apache

I am trying to set up `MapServer` with my existing `XAMPP` on Windows.

I downloaded `ms4w_4.0.5.zip` and extracted it into my `C://`-folder next to my `xampp`-folder. Now I would like to use `XAMPP` to run my `MapServer WFS`, but all documentation I found so far is always for setting up MapServer with the Apache server within the zipped folder...

I found this question: [How to install mapserver on Windows/Apache?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/150226/176525) from 5 years ago, but it did not really help me. Does someone have something like a step-by-step guide to also help others with this in the future?